# How do you get your program to repeat if input is invalid instead of continuing with invalid input?

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to validate a user input, cuPerTerm > 12

I get the error message but the program continues and uses the invalid input to run

```
package gradplanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradPlanner {

int cuToComp;
int cuPerTerm;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final double COST = 2890.00; //flat-rate tuition rate charged per term
    final int MONPERTERM = 6; //number of months per term
    int cuToCompTotal = 0;   
    int numTerm;
    int numMonToComp;
    double tuition;



      //prompt for user to input the number of CUs for each individual course remaining.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of CUs for each individual course you have remaining, Entering a - number when finished. ");     
    int cuToComp = in.nextInt();



      //add all CUs from individual courses to find the Total number of CUs left to complete.
    while (cuToComp > 0)
    {
      cuToCompTotal += cuToComp;

      System.out.print("Please enter the number of CUs for each individual course you have remaining, Entering a - number when finished. ");
      cuToComp = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("The total number of CUs left is " + cuToCompTotal);



      //prompt for user to input how many CUs they plan to take per term.
    System.out.print("How many credit units do you intend to take per term? ");
    int cuPerTerm = in.nextInt();

        if (cuPerTerm <12) //validate input - Undergraduate Students Must enroll in a minimum of 12 CUs per term
        {
            System.out.print("Undergraduate Students must enroll in a Minimum of 12 CUs per Term. ");

        }


        //Calculate the number of terms remaining, if a remain is present increase number of terms by 1.   
     numTerm = cuToCompTotal/cuPerTerm;
        if (cuToCompTotal%cuPerTerm > 0)
        {
          numTerm = numTerm + 1;  
        }
     System.out.println("The Number of Terms you have left is " + numTerm + " Terms. ");



       //Calculate the number of Months left to complete
     numMonToComp = numTerm * MONPERTERM;
     System.out.println("Which is " + numMonToComp + " Months. ");



       //calculate the tuition cost based on the number of terms left to complete.
     tuition = numTerm * COST;
     System.out.println("Your Total Tuition Cost is: " + "$" + tuition +" . ");

}
}
```

I need it to continue to re-ask until 12 or something greater is entered. and then continue the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `while` loop so that you continue looping until `cuPerTerm` is at least 12.  Remember to take the user input again with `cuPerTerm = in.nextInt();` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: I included a while loop which ask for the input but know it just keeps asking even if it is valid. do I need to type break; or something?

Comment: At the end of an iteration of the `while` loop, if the condition is no longer `true`, then the loop will end; no `break;` necessary.

Comment: never mind it needs to be cuPerTerm <12 to include 12 as a valid input I changed it so some reason to be <= so it wasn't including 12 it was saying it was invalid

Answer (score 1):

Add this to continue getting input till it satisfies your condition:

```
while(cuPerTerm <= 12){
//Ask use to provide input
}
```

It is simple while loop which checks your input condition and continues taking input till it is satisfied.

**Edit: -**
*Initialize your cuPerTerm  =0*

```
 while(cuPerTerm <= 12)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of CUs for each individual course you have remaining, Entering a - number when finished. ");     
        int cuToComp = in.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: I included a while loop which ask for the input but know it just keeps asking even if it is valid. do I need to type break; or something?

Comment: never mind it needs to be cuPerTerm <12 to include 12 as a valid input

Comment: @JessicaRush In your question check the first line it says `cuPerTerm > 12` meaning valid input should be greater than 12 (not including 12) hence my condition for invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
int cuPerTerm = -1; // intialize to an invalid value
while (cuPerTerm < 12) {
    System.out.print("How many credit units do you intend to take per term? ");
    int cuPerTerm = in.nextInt();

    if (cuPerTerm <12) { //validate input - Undergraduate Students Must enroll in a minimum of 12 CUs per term

        System.out.print("Undergraduate Students must enroll in a Minimum of 12 CUs per Term. ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are pitfalls: Simple doing `scanner.nextInt()` will give you the next Integer of the CURRENT Line.

If the user types in `test`, `nextInt()` will throw an `InputMismatchException`, you have to handle. **Also the int will NOT be consumed**

So you have to call `scanner.nextLine()` in between to Clean the current (mismatched) result.

All together something like this:

```
do{
    try
       {
       System.out.print("Enter number > 12: ");
       System.out.flush();
       number = scanner.nextInt(); 
       if (number > 12)
         done = true;
     }
     catch(InputMismatchException e) {
       System.out.println("This is not a number");
       scanner.nextLine() //!Important!
     }
   }while(!done);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a `do-while` loop will best suit your needs:

```
    int val;
    do {
        val = in.nextInt();
    } while (val < 12);
```